# iOS5 facebook integration

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I am trying to integrate "social option" to my app.

I have iOS6, but the idea is to have an app available for iOS5. Using Twitter framework it has been very simple and it works in devices with r.0 version and 6.0 version.

Regarding Facebook, I do not understand how integrate it. I just need the "post to wall" function.

I know that it exists in `social.framework` but does that in iOS5?

Answer (score 1):

Social framework does not exist in iOS 5. But facebook has a very extensive developer tutorial:
[Here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-ios/)

Comment: Thanks. Do you know what version of fb SDK I have to use for iOS5?

Comment: You can use latest version of Facebook SDK.

Answer (score 1):

If your app is targeting the iOS5+. then you need to implement Facebook Graph or Facebook SDK.

**Tutorial:**

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/

**Sample:**

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/tree/master/samples/Hackbook

I hope, Above tutorial & Sample app will help you for Facebook Integration in iOS5 devices.

Comment: Thanks. The seond link does not works. Is there any error on it?

Comment: Thanks for your tips. I finally use the sharekit project.

Answer (score -1):

For the latest version you need at least Xcode 4.5.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios-sdk-tutorial/